# Yii2 union query is not working in the server when deployed, but is working fine in local

Tags: yii2, union

I have a union query in my yii2 like given below

```
$variant_ids1=VariantProducts::find()
                ->select(['variant_id1'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->groupBy('variant_id1');
$variant_ids2=VariantProducts::find()
                ->select(['variant_id2'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->groupBy('variant_id2');
$variant_ids3=VariantProducts::find()
                ->select(['variant_id3'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->groupBy('variant_id3');
```

And i am joining them together using

```
$variant_ids1->union($variant_ids2);
$variant_ids1->union($variant_ids3);
```

The code is working fine in my local. But when i deployed in to the server , it is not working there.In the server i am getting an error like [check this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsFLa.png)

Comment: Why you want to union queries, you can concat the result of each query?

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA How can i do that, i am new in yii2

Comment: You are using windows in local e linux/unix on server ??

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes ,my local system is windows and the server is linux